# Regex to Find Certain URLs in String

Tags: php, regex

I'm not very good at Regex, but I've been working on improving. Right now I'm trying to make a regex expression to match all URLs in a string that follows a certain syntax. Here is my regex code:

```
@http://api\.ning\.com:80/files/[a-z0-9\*]/[a-z0-9\.]\.[jpg|png|gif|bmp]@i
```

Here is an example of something I want this to match (but it isn't matching):

```
http://api.ning.com:80/files/etWx3bZZxVPTI8A3sSd3zoLhhkTmjoCs2IRFnOacPoHzJogudMCze2mB2Fib0Z*R/ScreenShot20131111at4.58.13PM.png?width=375
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do two things:

1. Add a + at the end of group of characters [a-z0-9*] and [a-z0-9.]
2. Move the file extensions in parentheses instead of square brackets

The expression would become:

```
@http://api\.ning\.com:80/files/[a-z0-9\*]+/[a-z0-9\.]+\.(jpg|png|gif|bmp)@i
```

which can be further simplified to:

```
@http://api\.ning\.com:80/files/[\w\*]+/[\w\.]+\.(jpg|png|gif|bmp)@
```

Note that \w already includes upper-case and lower-case letters as well as numbers. So, you can get rid of the `i` flag too unless you need it for the file extensions or the base URL.

Comment: Don't you have to escape the slaches ?!

Comment: Not in PHP. That is a Java feature. Try it out here: http://regex101.com/r/vT6tE6. The forward slashes don't need to be escaped since the regex delimiter here is `@`.

Comment: I suspected it... thks for the info :)

Comment: Nice catch at the end.  I didn't look past the first error, force of habit.

Comment: Wouldn't the i flag check for different case situations for the file extensions too though?

Comment: Awesome! That works for the example I gave! But quick additional question: What if there was a hyphen in the block after "/files/"? I tried changing it to "[\w\*\-]" but that didn't find anything

Comment: Let me check that too. Do you have a sample URL you want to match? `http://api\.ning\.com:80/files/[\w\*\-]+/[\w\.]+\.(jpg|png|gif|bmp)` matches `http://api.ning.com:80/files/etWx3bZZxVPTI8A3sSd3zoLhhkTmjoCs2IRFnOacPoHzJogudMC-ze2mB2Fib0Z*R/ScreenShot20131111at4.58.13PM.png?width=375`. I think you missed the back slash before the *.